# Can't get WebDings font to work in Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, fonts, flash-builder

I want to add the WebDings font to my Flex application. The folder structure is:

```
assets
> style.css
> WebDings.ttf
src
> MyApp.mxml
```

In my style.css file I have:

```
@font-face {
    src: url("WebDings.ttf");
    fontFamily: webdings;
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

s|global {
    font-family: webdings;
}
```

However all my Spark components show up as Times New Roman. Does anyone know how I can get this working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src: url("WebDings.ttf");` should be `src: url("assets/WebDings.ttf");`

Answer (score 0):

try adding something like that:

**Application {
    font-family: WebDings;
}**

Answer (score 0):

move assets folder to in the src folder and do this src: url("assets/WebDings.ttf");
or leave the folder where it is and include the path into your build path.